# function not working when content parameters are very long

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I call a function named mySQLQuery_exist that returns a "boolean" which I test under "if", it is giving me error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" when i call it.

```
 ....

     // blue syntax error appears on mySQLQuery_exist         
     if (mySQLQuery_exist("1", "SELECT fld_logUserName,fld_logPassword FROM tbl_SystemAccess where fld_logUserName = '" + var_words[1].Trim() + "' AND " + "fld_logPassword = '" + var_words[2].Trim() + "' AND fld_logIPAddress = '" + var_words[3].Trim() + "'", "CIS"))

      ....

.....

//if it helps this is how i declared my function
public Boolean mySQLQuery_exist(string var_SQLConnector, string var_SQLCommand, string var_SQLdatabase)

.....
```

i just wanted to return false if there is no record and true if it found at least 1 record

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the relevant part? I'm not seeing any assignments in it anywhere!

Comment: You are talking about a function, not a class.

Comment: Classes in C# cannot return values. There are methods, fields and properties that do that (in a broad sense). Try compiling your code and post the error returned along with the line the error is applying to.

Comment: sorry yup it is a function still studying c#... i'll add more codes if it helps

Comment: i guess the problem is with your second string,i would format it to string before passing it to the method

Comment: Please remove SQL injection (by using parametrized queries) - it may also fix your problem.

Comment: i move the 2nd string to the string variable named var_select and it worked well ... problem solve, thank you very much... i do find that strange though LOL

Comment: You probably should delete your question or come up with clear sample and that feel free to answer and accept. Note that showing code with SQL injection issues is generally not welcome on SO (unless your question is explicitly about that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the codes that worked for me:

```
    string var_Select = "SELECT ....WHERE...";

   //test boolean result from mySQLQuery_exist
    if (mySQLQuery_exist(var_Select))
    {
    ....
    ....

    // function to check if any records found or none
    public Boolean mySQLQuery_exist(string var_SQLCommand)
    {
        Boolean var_Result = false;

        using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(var_pubicSQLConnect))
        using (SqlCommand var_command = new SqlCommand(var_SQLCommand, myConn))
        {
            myConn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader var_RS = var_command.ExecuteReader())

                if (var_RS.Read())
                    var_Result = true;
        }
        return var_Result;            
    }
```

It seemed that if a function parameter is too long and is composed of SQL String, it gives that error. What I've done is put all parameter as public except the SQL query which i contained into a variable and passed down to my function. The function return true or false depending if it found any records as per the SQL query.

thank you for your help.